# append images using a grid

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

```
convert +append ...
```

appends images horizontally.

```
convert -append ...
```

appends images vertically.

Imagine i have a set of N images and i want to create to append the images following a grid of N/2 lines and 2 columns. How can i do that?

The best will be a direct method, but if it involves temporary images, it's ok for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the ImageMagick "montage" command, specifically the "-tile" option. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/ for details.

Comment: Indeed, convert is not the only binary provided by imagemagick. Thanks!