# Use imagemagic to put several JPG on one page

Tags: imagemagick

I have a folder full of jpg files. When I use the following command,

`convert *.jpg assembly.pdf`

I get a pdf file with one image per page of the pdf. I would like to put 9 images on each page. Is there a way to do this with convert or mogrify?

Alternatively, I'd like to combine 9 of the jpg images into one jpg image so that I can convert that into a PDF.

Thanks,

z.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append images using a grid](http://superuser.com/questions/317615/append-images-using-a-grid)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're looking for `montage` from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) :

```
NAME
       montage  - create a composite image by combining several sepa‐
       rate images. The images  are  tiled  on  the  composite  image
       optionally adorned with a border, frame, image name, and more.
```

If you already have `convert` then you almost certainly also have `montage`. To get a grid of 3x3 images per page on your pdf try this:

```
 montage *.jpg -tile 3x3 assembly.pdf
```

This assumes your images all have roughly the same size. Have a read through the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) for more complex options.

Comment: This was great! We used `montage *.jpg -tile 3x3 -geometry 1000 assembly.pdf` to get 9 high quality images per page. We tried it on a sample of 30 images or so, and it worked like a charm! Then we tried to run the full 400 images and... my computer started chirping and seizing, and it consumed 95% of the ram. Eventually we got the message "killed" in the terminal... probably we'll have to run this in batches! :) Anyway, thanks man! I'm going to read the docs in detail, because imagemagick seems like supreme command-line sorcery.

Comment: I suggest to montage the images into jpg first, and then convert the jpg into pdf.
Somehow the size is exploded if you convert into pdf directly.